# How to bring the electron app on the foreground after a successful google oauth2 callback from the browser on Windows OS?

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application

I have created a simple app that uses google oauth2 authentication. I have used the `open()` method to load the google auth page on the default browser instead of creating a secondary window on an app itself.
And when google auth successfully authorized, I call the following code on the main process

```
ipcMain.on('signin-successful', (event, arg) => {
  mainWindow.loadFile('home.html')
  mainWindow.show();
})
```

In mac OS, it is working perfectly fine. After login success, the electron app comes in the foreground as focused. But on Windows OS app does not come in the foreground; instead, the app icon at the start bar (windows start bar) keeps blinking. Is there any way to bring the app to the foreground as in mac OS?

*Note: I have tried other functions like `restore()` and `focus(),` but none of them worked for me.*

Answer (score 1):

I found it to be a weird behavior of windows 10 ([reference](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/18046))

And a minimal solution to show browserWindow to foreground is:

```
function BringMainWindowToForeground() {
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
  mainWindow.show();
}
```